# Read emails from /usr/bin/mail using php

Tags: php, linux, email

For simple testing purposes I am sending mail locally on my linux machine. I can see the received mails by simply typing `mail` on the command line. I now want to get an array of those received emails from within php. Does anybody know how I can do that?

All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
To explain. When I send an email to 'kramer65@localhost' from within php, I can see the email by running `mail` which refers to /usr/bin/mail. The output of this is something like this:

```
Mail version 8.1.2 01/15/2001.  Type ? for help.
"/var/mail/kramer65": 1 message 1 new
>N  1 kramer65@php0        Fri Apr 25 11:49   16/501   THIS IS THE SUBJECT
& 
Message 1:
From kramer65@php0  Fri Apr 25 11:49:25 2014
X-Original-To: kramer65@localhost
To: kramer65@localhost
Subject: THIS IS THE SUBJECT
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1007:php shell code
Date: Fri, 25 Apr 2014 11:49:25 +0200 (CEST)
From: kramer65@php0 (kramer65)

THIS IS THE BODY OF THE MESSAGE
```

I now want to get the output those emails in an array in php. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: What about [`passthru`](http://php.net/passthru) or [`popen`](http://php.net/popen)

Answer (score 0):

You can load the received-email-file(s) into a string using file_get_contents('filename');
If you want to make a multidimensional array there should have to be a certain structure in the received-email-file to separate email sender, title, text, etc. in your php code.

If you can't (or don't want to) separate sender, title, text, etc you can still make an array of the complete mails.

if you save each email in a separate file it would look something like this:

```
$directory = 'path/to/your/mails/';
$files = glob($directory.'*.txt');
$filescount = count($files);
$mailArray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $filescount; $i++)
{
  $mailString = file_get_contents('mail'.$i);
  $mailArray[] = $mailString;
}
```

In this example i presume the filetype of your mail is .txt
also the filenames of the mails would have to be mail0, mail1, mail2 etc.

If I misunderstood the question completely I am sorry ;)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Although it isn't really an answer to my question, it already helps. My question is more about reading out the result of `mail`. I added some more information to the question.

Comment: oh okay in this context i have no experience at all.
can't help you further, sry

Answer (score 0):

The mail spool on a Unix system is a simple flat text file in something called Berkeley [`mbox`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) format.

To modify it, you need to use the same locking mechanism as the `mail` program (so that the file is not changed by another program while you modify it) but to just read it, it's fine to open, read a line at a time, start a new message when you see the sequence `(start of file, or newline)From` and close when you're done.

(I'm not familiar with PHP but I imagine you should be able to find a library which does this. If you're lucky, it's secure and bug-free.)

The [Procmail](http://www.procmail.org/) suite contains a utility called `formail` which can spawn a new program (such as a PHP script of yours) on each message in an `mbox` file. There is another utility `lockfile` which knows how to properly lock the mailbox file.